# React Native EStyleSheet how to apply multiple styles

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I'm new to React Native [EStyleSheet](https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet) lib. I find it's really cool, but one thing that I can't figure out is, how to apply multiple styles to a single element just like I used to do with regular styles with `style={{...styles.style1, ...styles.style2}}`?

```
render() {
    return <View style={estyles.container}>
        <View style={{...estyles.container, ...estyles.containerInner}}>
            <Text>Hello, World!</View>
        </View>
    <View>

}

const estyles = EStyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        padding: '2%',
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        borderRadius: 1,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'black'
    },
    containerInner: {
        padding: '5%'
    }
});
```

Comment: Try `style={[estyles.container, estyles.containerInner]}`

Answer (score 1):

**You can use array of styles to apply multiple styles to single view**

example

```
<View style={[styles.container, styles.view,...]}>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can used in style array of styles for example:

```
render() {
    return <View style={estyles.container}>
        <View style={[estyles.container,estyles.containerInner]}>
            <Text>Hello, World!</View>
        </View>
    <View>

}

const estyles = EStyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        padding: '2%',
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        borderRadius: 1,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'black'
    },
    containerInner: {
        padding: '5%'
    }
});
```

this => [estyles.container,estyles.containerInner] can used